# AVl Tree adoption

Tags: rotation, avl-tree

So say I've inserted these numbers to an AVL tree: 40, 20, 25, 60, 65, 70. My tree should look like:

```
                             25                                                                 
                            /  \                                                                
                           20   60                                                                
                                / \                                                             
                               40  65                                                             
                                     \                                                         
                                      70
```

Which means doing a rotation with an adoption, like this?

```
                                       60                                                       
                                      /  \                                                    
                                     25   65                                                    
                                     / \    \                                                  
                                    20  40   70
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, Yes

Try finding the source code for an existing implementation, that should help you in the future.